# Google SEO no blue buttons appearing

Tags: seo, google-search, microdata

## TL;DR

The most important links are the following;

- `/reserveren` (aka book now page)
- `/veelgestelde-vragen` (aka FAQ page)

but not appearing in Google search results

---

I’m currently optimising my SEO for my website. But I don’t get any blue buttons like my competitor (see the image, I removed all the text because else I advertise here).

[image: Google search result]

**SiteLink Searchbox (microdata):**
I guess that the blue buttons are [SiteLinks](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox) I added the following:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "https://site-url.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://site-url.com/faq/{search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}

</script>
```

But that seems to be a search box? Are those blue buttons breadcrumbs then or should I add something else to my code? To get blue buttons in the search result?

**Navigation:**
Code inside my `nav` element:

```
    <div class="w-full block flex-grow md:inline-block md:w-auto hidden">
        <a href="/reserveren" class="classes">Reserveren</a>
        <a href="/#het-verhaal" class="classes">Het verhaal</a>
        <a href="/#wat-ga-je-doen" class="classes">Wat ga je doen?</a>
        <a href="/#voor-wie" class="classes">Voor wie?</a>
        <a href="/#prijzen" class="classes">Prijzen</a>
        <a href="/veelgestelde-vragen" class="classes">Veelgestelde vragen</a>
        <a href="/#contact" class="classes">Contact</a>
    </div>
```

**Sitemap:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://my-site.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-02-01</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://my-site.com/reserveren</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-02-01</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://my-site.com/veelgestelde-vragen</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-02-01</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://my-site.com/#welkom</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-01-31</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>2</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://my-site.com/#het-verhaal</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-01-31</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>2</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://my-site.com/#wat-ga-je-doen</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-01-31</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>2</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://my-site.com/#voor-wie</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-01-31</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>2</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://my-site.com/#prijzen</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-01-31</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>2</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://my-site.com/#contact</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-01-31</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>2</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those blue buttons are indeed site links. I believe if you do your internal linking from the home page correctly, and if you set your priorities in the sitemap correctly, you should also start seeing them.

Comment: I added extra information to my question like navigation code and sitemap. I guess based on your answer that possibly my navigation is incorrect?